# Jenkins: avax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 Incorrect authentication data

Tags: jenkins, centos6

I have installed Jekins on my VPS (Centos6) and did the follwing configuration in order to receive email notifications:
[image]

Note that this configuration worked for me when I was using jenkins on localhost (windows)
And of course I have enabled `Less secured app` option in my gmail account
What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your centos vps , you don't have a relay for gmail host, so you can try to send email notifications from your server smtp.localhost with port 25 and without authentication (don't forget to set your system administrator email, you'll find it within Jenkins Location at the top)